# rosserial_windows help,compile error on windows

Tags: rosserial, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I`m trying to use  rosserial_windows .
And I operate as the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World) instructed .
The difference is that I use visual studio 2010.

After Step 4--Add code to main for Hello World,  I begin to build the code on visual studio 2010.
And there are same errors with these two documents, `duration.h` , `time.h` :

```
error C3861: 'round': identifier not found
```

how can i solve this problem?

Is that because I didn`t use visual studio 2013 like the tutorial does??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270379/rosserial_windows-help,compile-error-on-windows/) by [JohnBT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31607/johnbt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

VS2010 doesn't support c99.
VS2013 will work out.

---

Originally posted by [JohnBT](https://answers.ros.org/users/31607/johnbt/) with karma: 30 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0